# vue js infinity scroll changing link when next page is visible

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, infinite-scroll

When the user is navigation in the blog page for instance and when he gets to the bottom of the page, the same page loads a new article and the URL changes.
Example: www.teste.blog/article/this-article to www.teste.blog/article/the-other-article

Something like this : https://streamable.com/s/tii95/mffepe (npm infinite-scroll package)

**Is there a package to achieve something like this with vue js ?**

Comment: I don't know a library that implements this is vue, but it is rather easy to implement yourself. Take a look at `intersectionObserver`. You can use this to recognize when a user scrolled to the bottom of your page and simply direct him to a a new article with `$router.push()`

Comment: Here are 2 packages to support this: https://github.com/ElemeFE/vue-infinite-scroll or https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/infiniteScroll

Comment: I think both of them cannot change the url .

Comment: @MarcRo , i'm already using `intersectionObserver` with polyfill for order browsers. I want to manipulate the url maybe a watch with this.$router.replace({})

Comment: That should work as well. Either load a new route - or make a request to replace the data and replace the route.